# Pandas dropna does not work as expected on a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a multiIndex. The index consists of a date and a text string. Some of the values are NaN and when I use dropna(), the row disappears as expected. However, when I look at the index using df.index, the dropped dates are still there. This is problematic as when I use the to_panel function, the dropped dates reappear.

Am I using dropna incorrectly or how can I resolve this?

Comment: But maybe it is issue - https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2770

Comment: Yes, it appears to be that issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is issue [2770](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2770).

And solution is decribe [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2770#issuecomment-76500001).

```
index.get_level_values(level)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this actually worked :

`df1=df1[pd.notnull(df1['Cloumn Name'])]`